# Javascript multiple matches for IF

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to detect images in javascript, this is what I thought would work but it isn't. How can I do it correctly?

```
if (url.substr(url.length - 3 ) == 'gif' || 'jpg' || 'png')
```

Comment: What led you to believe that would work?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the `||` in that fashion. You'd have to re-write the if statement as:

```
var lastThree = url.substr(url.length - 3);
if(lastThree == 'gif' ||
   lastThree == 'jpg' ||
   lastThree == 'png')
{
    // do something
}
```

Or you could use an array (which I would prefer personally):

```
if(['gif','jpg','png'].indexOf(url.substr(url.length - 3)) > -1)
{
    // do something
}
```

You should also use the `toLowerCase()` method on the URL substring, since some image files might end in JPG or GIF for example.

Comment: EDIT: suggested use of toLowerCase method

Answer (score 1):

You seem to misunderstand what an OR does:

```
var ext = url.substr(url.length - 3 );
if (ext == 'gif' || ext == 'jpg' || ext == 'png') {
   ..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression:

```
if (/gif|jpg|png/i.test(url.substr(url.length - 3 )))
```

Note that *jpg* can also be *jpeg*, *gif* might be *giff* and there is also *tiff* and other formats. And the extension is not reliable to determine a file format.

#### Edit

And as Cookie Monster suggests, you can save a bit of typing using:

```
/(gif|jpg|png)$/i.test(url)
```

and just add extras as required:

```
/(gif|jpg|jpeg|jfif|png|tiff|raw|bmp|svg)$/i.test(url)
```

Comment: If you're going to use a regexp, why not just anchor it to the end of the string instead of using `substr`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the complete condition after `||`

```
    var src = url.substr(url.length - 3 );
    if (src === 'gif' || src === 'jpg' || src === 'png')
```

`===` is used to check the value and type.